# Why did my wireless USB adapter suddenly stop working on a powered USB hub after it worked for weeks?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, usb-power, wireless-adapter, usb-hub

I set up two Raspberry Pis to power a 50" television each about a month ago. On each I have Raspbian running, with slight modifications so that it boots into a Midori browser kiosk that, by default, navigates to a URL that displays a metrics dashboard. This URL is the only thing that differs between them; otherwise both have completely identical setups, in terms of hardware and software.

They were working fine for weeks, until a few days ago, when the browser suddenly kept on being unable to load the URL because it wasn't connected to the internet. I was able to get the connection up again with `sudo ifup wlan0`, though it continued to be flaky. And then finally the connection died out completely and I wasn't even able to bring it back up.

Upon further investigation, it seemed that `wlan0` just *disappeared* altogether (from what I could see when I ran `ifconfig`, anyway). On the other hand, the wireless adapter still showed up in the `lsusb` output.

It seems odd to me that it worked for so long before this happened. I don't think it's a problem with my scripts, but I'll include them here anyway.

Hardware list (for each setup):

- [Belkin USB 2.0 Plus Hub](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F5U304/)
- [ASUS N150 wireless USB adapter](http://www.asus.com/Networking/USBN10/) (connected to the aforementioned USB hub)
- 5V 1.5A power supply ([this exact one](https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi-accessories/power-supply/raspberry-pi-power-supply-us))
- [Philips 50PFL3908 LED-LCD TV](http://www.usa.philips.com/c-p/50PFL3908_F7/3000-series-led-lcd-tv)

Here are the relevant files that have been changed/added:

`/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

sudo xinit /home/pi/start_midori.sh &
exit 0
```

`/home/pi/start_midori.sh` (where `www.google.com` is just a placeholder for the actual default URL I was pointing it to):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true ; do
  xset -dpms        # disable DPMS (Energy Star) features
  xset s off        # disable screensaver
  xset s noblank    # don't blank the video device

  unclutter &       # hide the mouse pointer
  matchbox-window-manager &

  WEBKIT_IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS=1 midori -e Fullscreen -a 'www.google.com'
done
```

I'm not sure what's happened but if anyone has any idea why the wireless interface suddenly dropped out, any advice or suggestions would be highly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** It started working after I plugged the adapter straight into the Pi, versus in the USB hub. So, the question, rephrased: why did it suddenly stop working on the hub after it had been working for so long?

Comment: Weird hardware problems often seem to be power related, have you checked with a different power supply and/or a powered hub?

Comment: Wow ok. After all that, when I moved the wireless adapter to plug in straight into the USB port on the Pi (vs. the USB hub), everything magically started working again.